# %%j and %%S in format string for frame-title-format

Tags: org-mode, init-file

In my cobbled-together init.el, my frame-title-format variable has these %-sequences in it: %%j and %%S

Does anyone recognize these specific sequences? They come up blank in my frame title. Here's the full variable def:

```
(setq frame-title-format
  (list (format "%s %%S: %%j " (system-name))
        '(buffer-file-name "%f" (dired-directory dired-directory "%b"))))
```

This evaluates to

```
("mySystemName %S: %j "
 (buffer-file-name "%f"
                    (dired-directory dired-directory "%b")))
```

and displays in my frame as, for example when visiting a help topic, as

```
mySystemName : *Help*
```

Comment: A single quote inhibits evaluation of what is inside the list that is quoted.   See the section of the manual regarding the usage of a single quote versus a backtick and comma combination:  https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Backquote.html  You may also wish to use the function `list` instead of a single quote ...

Comment: @Drew: no, his quoted list seems perfectly valid: it's not an Elisp expression to be evaluated but a mode-line-format expression where `(SYM A B)` uses A is SYM is non-nil and B otherwise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, the string is transformed by `format`. Looking at its Help, we discover that the instances of `%%` will be changed to a single %, so that we are left with `%S` and `%j`.

Now we look at the Help for `frame-title-format`:

> This variable has the same structure as ‘mode-line-format’

So, clicking over to `mode-line-format`, we find the full list of %-constructs. I don't see `%S` or `%j` in this list, which must be why they appear blank.

Comment: Ok. I thought that **might** be the case, but since I saw this elisp used in several different `init.el` files. I wondered if I was missing some more advanced explanation. I've been digging through the Emacs source -- back to 2003, which is the earliest reference I could find that used this elisp -- to see if perhaps there was an %-construct that was removed. I haven't found either one mentioned in `buffer.c`.

Comment: It's possible that these constructs are valid but not documented. I'm not able to dive into the C source to check this, as I didn't build my Emacs myself. Then again, if the constructs were valid, something would likely be showing up in the frame title...

Comment: It looks like you used to use XEmacs, which allowed '%S' for the name of the frame. That didn't support '%j' though, as far as I can tell.