# Frame number in frame title - how?

Tags: frames

I want to use two frames. One on virtual desktop #1 and the other one on #2. I (have to) work on Windows so I would like to see a frame number in the frame title, since Windows lacks a permanently visible virtual desktop indicator.
I thought I just add a frame counter variable to frame-title-format and I'm good to go, but it seems there is none. My current frame-title-format:

```
(setq frame-title-format '("%b" "   " buffer-file-name))
```

I'm lacking coding skills, and I couldn't find any solution using Google/SE search.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [%%j and %%S in format string for frame-title-format](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/47036/j-and-s-in-format-string-for-frame-title-format)

Comment: I found https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/frame-cmds.el which seems to contain functions that seem to be close but nothing seems to work out of the box for me but maybe someone can extract relevant information from it.